# Help with the integrability of a function throughout $\mathbb{R}^n$

Tags: indefinite-integrals, riemann-integration

Given a continuous function $f\colon \mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}$ such that, for some M, R, p constant values:

$$\vert f(x) \vert \leq \frac{M}{\vert\vert x \vert\vert^p}$$

If $\vert\vert x \vert\vert\geq R$ and $p>n$. Then the integral over the entire space $\mathbb{R}^n$ exists.

Now, so far I've realized that for $R> 1, M>0$ the exponential function $g(x)=R^x$ is increasing. Therefore, given $p>n \implies \vert\vert x \vert\vert^p> \vert\vert x \vert\vert^n \implies \frac{M}{\vert\vert x \vert\vert^p}<\frac{M}{\vert\vert x \vert\vert^n}$

So $\vert f(x) \vert < \frac{M}{\vert\vert x \vert\vert^n}$. This tells me that the function is bounded, but I'm not sure where to go from here. Are there any theorems or lemmas that could help with the proof?

Thank you so much!

Comment: What do you mean by the ``integral over the whole space?" If you are talking about Riemann integrals, then the Riemann integral of $g(x):=|f(x)|$ is going to exist whenever $g$ is restricted to a compact subset of $\mathbb{R}^{n}$ because $f$ is assumed to be continuous (and therefore so is $g=|\cdot|\circ f$.

Comment: Use polar coordinates in $\mathbb R^{n}$ for the integral over $\{x: \|x\| >1\}$.

Comment: @JWP_HTX I meant that $\int_{\mathbb{R}^n} f$ exists

Comment: You need to do a little work and make some adjustments, but consider $\sum_{k=R}^\infty ((k+1)^n-k^n) S {1 \over k^p}$ where $S$ is the volume of the unit ball. Since $(x+1)^n-x^n$ is a polynomial of degree $n-1$ you can bound this.

Answer (score 1):

This is an improper Riemann integral.

To show that $\lim_{r \to \infty} \int_{\|x\| \le r} f$ exists, it
is sufficient to show that $\lim_{r \to \infty} \int_{\|x\| \le r} f_+$ and $\lim_{r \to \infty} \int_{\|x\| \le r} f_-$ exist, where $f_+=\max(f,0), f_- = \max(-f,0)$. Since $f_+, f_-$ are continuous, and are bounded above by $|f|$, it is sufficient to show that $\lim_{r \to \infty} \int_{\|x\| \le r} |f|$ exists (and is finite).

Note that if $0 \le h \le g$ and $g$ is improperly integrable, then $h$ is improperly integrable.

In the above case, it is sufficient to show that $\int_{R \le \|x\| \le r} {1 \over \|x\|^p} dx$ exists (and is finite). For simplicity we can assume that $R$ is an integer.

Let $S$ be the volume of $B(0,1)$, note that the volume of $B(0,r)$ is $S^n$.
Let $g$ be the function
$g(x) = \sum_{k=R}^\infty 1_{B(0,k+1)\setminus B(0,k)}(x) {1 \over k^p}$,
note that $g(x) = {1 \over \lfloor \|x\| \rfloor^p} \ge {1 \over \|x\|^p}$ for $\|x\| \ge R$. Note that the set of discontinuities of $g$ have measure zero, and hence $g$ is integrable on any closed ball of finite radius.

We have $\int_{\|x\| \le r} g \le \sum_{k=R}^\infty ((k+1)^n-k^n) S {1 \over k^p}$, and $p(x) = (x+1)^n -x^n$ is a polynomial of degree $n-1$ and since $p-(n-1) > 1$ we see that the series is summable and hence $\lim_{r \to \infty} \int_{\|x\| \le r} g$ exists and so $f$ is integrable.